# Replacement for ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```sql
SELECT  flatNo, 
        name ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY flatNo, name
              ORDER BY flatNo ASC, name ASC
        ) No
FROM    flats
```

SQL output:

| flatNo | name | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f0001 | flat01 | 1 |
| f0002 | flat02 | 1 |
| f0002 | flat02 | 2 |
| f0003 | flat03 | 1 |

Is there any alternative for this `partition by`  function in JavaScript?

Sample input:

```js
[
    { flatNo: 'flat01', name: 'flat01' },
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02' },
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02' }
    { flatNo: 'flat03', name: 'flat03' }
]
```

Desired output:

```js
[
    { flatNo: 'flat01', name: 'flat01', count:1 },
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02', count:1 },
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02', count:2 }
    { flatNo: 'flat03', name: 'flat03', count:1 }
]
```

Comment: You should provide the input that you would have for JavaScript.

Comment: @trincot the input can be any collection

Comment: Input Format :{ flatNo: 'flat01', name: 'flat01'},
  { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02' },
  { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02'}
  { flatNo: 'flat03', name: 'flat03'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define some generic functions that deal with parts of the logic:

- `compare`: allowing to compare two rows of data by selected field(s). Outcome can be -1, 0 or 1 (less than, equal, greater than).
- `orderBy`: order a data set by the given field(s)
- `partitionBy`: create partitions (subarrays) by the given fields(s)
- `rowNumber`: add a column to the data, where each row gets a sequence number. If the data is partitioned (i.e. multilevel), then the numbering restarts at every sub array.

You can then apply the native `.flat()` method whenever you want to get from the partitioned data set back to a flat array.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
function compare(fields, a, b) {
    for (let field of fields) {
        if (a[field] < b[field]) return -1;
        if (a[field] > b[field]) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

const orderBy = (data, ...fields) =>
    [...data].sort(compare.bind(null, fields));

const partitionBy = (data, ...fields) =>
    // Will not order the data before partitioning
    data.reduce((acc, row) => {
        if (acc.length && !compare(fields, acc[acc.length-1][0], row)) {
            acc[acc.length - 1].push(row);
        } else {
            acc.push([row]);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

const rowNumber = (data, alias="rownumber") =>
    Array.isArray(data[0]) // partitioned ? recur for each!
        ? data.map(row => rowNumber(row, alias))
        : data.map((row, i) => ({...row, [alias]: i+1 })); // base case

// Demo
let data = [
    { flatNo: 'flat01', name: 'flat01'}, 
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02'}, 
    { flatNo: 'flat02', name: 'flat02'},
    { flatNo: 'flat03', name: 'flat03'}
];

let result = rowNumber(
    partitionBy(
        orderBy(data, "flatNo", "name"), // fields to order by
        "flatNo", "name" // fields to partition by
    ),
    "count" // The alias for the additional row-number column
).flat(); // Finally flatten away the partitions

console.log(result);
```